# SQLAlchemy Get Raw SQL Value from TypeDecorator

Tags: python, sql, enums, sqlalchemy

I have defined the following custom type for sqlalchemy:

```
class EnumColumnType(TypeDecorator):
    impl = Integer

    def __init__(self, enum, *args, **kwargs):
        self.enum = enum
        super(EnumColumnType, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return None
        return value.value

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return None
        return self.enum(value)

    @property
    def python_type(self):
        return int
```

Essentially, it encapsulates a python enum and writes it back as an integer to the sql table.

Assume I have the following enum defined:

```
class Bar(Enum):
    foo = 1
    bar = 2
    baz = 3
```

Assume I have a model as follows:

```
class Foo(base):
    enum = Column(EnumColumnType(Bar))
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

If I have an instance of Foo i.e. `row = Foo(enum=Bar.baz)`, is it possible for me to get the sql type of `row.enum`? Currently, `row.enum` correctly evaluates to `Bar.baz`, but I would like to get 3, the value being written to the sql table. Is it possible to do this? Note that the `EnumColumnType`, `Bar` and `Foo` are defined correctly since sqlalchemy correctly persists rows to the table.

Comment: Do you just want `row.enum.value`?

Comment: Yes, but I want it to be general - it should behave the same way for any valid sqlalchemy column type (even potentially other type decorators)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an SQLAlchemy user, but I can say that the point of `Enum` is to provide a textual representation of a unique value.

From your description I think you would be best served by an `IntEnum` which, while still having a textual representation of `Bar.foo` or `Bar.baz` would still be directly usable as the `int` `1` or `3`